# Get Top N row from each set from table with 4 column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have a table with 4 columns:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
```

My initial query is :

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4  
FROM myTable  
ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3 DESC, Col4
```

My desired result is all 4 columns, but with this condition that Top N Col3   different row when Col1, Col2 is equal.

Example with N=2 :

Table sample data:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4  
---------------------
1    a    2000  s  
1    a    2002  c  
1    a    2001  b  
2    b    1998  s  
2    b    2002  c  
2    b    2000  b  
3    c    2000  b  
1    f    1998  n  
1    g    1999  e
```

Desired result:

```
1    a    2002  c  
1    a    2001  b  
1    f    1998  n  
1    g    1999  e  
2    b    2002  c  
2    b    2000  b  
3    c    2000  b
```

In another description, when `(col1, col2)` is repeated in multiple records, just export top N rows of those records when order by Col3 descending.

Can I do this with SQL script, without hard coding?

Comment: use group by clause for columns and then use order by col3 desc to get our desired output

Comment: 4 _columns_, not fields.

Comment: group by in SQL in my question do not suitable , because field have different value and when group by columns, each value go to own group and cannot access to do Top N Col3 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t table (Col1 int, Col2 char, Col3 int,  Col4 char);

insert into @t values  
(1,    'a',    2000,  's'),  
(1,    'a',    2002,  'c'),  
(1,    'a',    2001,  'b'),  
(2,    'b',    1998,  's'),  
(2,    'b',    2002,  'c'),  
(2,    'b',    2000,  'b'),  
(3,    'c',    2000,  'b'),  
(1,    'f',    1998,  'n'),  
(1,    'g',    1999,  'e');


declare @N int = 2; -- number per "top"

with cte as
(
select *,
       row_number() over(partition by col1, col2 order by col3 desc) as rn
from @t
)

select *
from cte c
where rn <= @N;
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and tested answer, That's very nice answer

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1- FOR MSSQL**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4bda39/6

```
with a as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t.col1,t.col2 order by t.col3 desc) as row,t.* 
    from myTable as t) 
select * from a where a.row <= 2
```

Replace **a.row <= 2** (2 with your N)

**METHOD 2- FOR MYSQL**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79e81a/63

```
SELECT   myTable.Col1, myTable.Col2, myTable.Col3, myTable.Col4
FROM ( 
    Select Col1 as Col1, Col2 as Col2, count(Col1) as cc, AVG(Col3) as aa 
    From myTable 
    group by Col1, Col2) as tt
join  myTable on myTable.Col1 = tt.Col1 and myTable.Col2 = tt.Col2
where myTable.Col3 >= tt.aa
Order by Col1 ,Col2 ,Col3 Desc,Col4
```

**METHOD 3- FOR MYSQL**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79e81a/79

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT CASE Col1
        WHEN @Col1 THEN
            CASE Col2 
                WHEN @Col2 THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                ELSE @curRow := 1
            END
        ELSE @curRow :=1
    END AS rank,
    @Col1 := Col1 AS Col1,
    @Col2 := Col2 AS Col2, 
    Col3, Col4
    FROM myTable p
    JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0, @Col1 := 0, @Col2 := '') r
    ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3 DESC) as tt 
WHERE tt.rank <= 2
```

Replace **tt.rank <= 2**  replace 2 by your desired index

Comment: please pay attention to question , When (Col1 , Col2 ) is repeated in multiple row , my desire result is Top N Record that order by Col3

Comment: made little changes now

Answer (score 0):

I think below code was as expected

```
declare @tab table (Col1 int, Col2 char(1), Col3 int, Col4 char(1))
declare @N int
insert into @tab
select 1,    'a'   , 2000,  's' 
union all
select 1 ,   'a'  ,  2002 , 'c'  
union all
select 1 ,   'a'  ,  2001 , 'b'  
union all
select 2 ,   'b'  ,  1998 , 's'  
union all
select 2 ,   'b'  ,  2002  ,'c'  
union all
select 2 ,   'b'  ,  2000  ,'b'  
union all
select 3 ,   'c'  ,  2000  ,'b'  
union all
select 1 ,   'f'  ,  1998  ,'n'  
union all
select 1 ,   'g'  ,  1999  ,'e'

;with tab as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t.col1,t.col2 order by t.col3 desc) as row,t.* 
from @tab t
)

select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 
from tab
where row < 3
```

output

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1        a      2002    c
1        a      2001    b
1        f      1998    n
1        g      1999    e
2        b      2002    c
2        b      2000    b
3        c      2000    b
```

Comment: Thanks but Max return Top Col3 Value But i wish N record of group when order by Col3 that describe in example

Comment: Thanks , But Condition is :  When in multiple record that have  (Col1,Col2) Equal , just Export Top N Record of this records that Order by Of Col3 Descending , Excuse me ,  it clear or i must describe more?